# How to display MySQL data in bar chart in Unity

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, bar-chart, mysql-connector

I am new to unity and I am trying to display data from MySQL database into unity and show them in a bar chart. But I have no idea where to start. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't one single thing you are trying to do. It's several things that are well documented.

1. How to connect to MySQL server. [https://dotnetfiddle.net/aMxIOM]
2. Query data on MySQL server and return as `List<T>`. [Same Link as Above]
3. Create a bar chart [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmU57Ka9H0E]
4. Populate barchart with data from sql server.

Try to break your problem up into smaller more manageable sections, and try to find out how to do them. Usually just go to YouTube "***What I want to know*** Tutorial"